# Taglib to display java.time.LocalDate formatted

Tags: java, jsp, date, java-8, taglib

I would like to display formatted `java.time.LocalDate` in my JSP. Do you know any taglib to use for this?

For `java.util.Date` we were using `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>`. Does something similar for `java.time.LocalDate` exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516766/jstl-formatdate-and-java-time-localdate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Afsun's hints inspired me to create a quick solution.

1. Under `/WEB-INF` create directory `tags`.
2. Create tag file `localDate.tag` inside the `tags` directory.
3. Put bellow code into this tag file:

   ```
   <%@ tag body-content="empty" pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>

   <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

   <%@ attribute name="date" required="true" type="java.time.LocalDate" %>
   <%@ attribute name="pattern" required="false" type="java.lang.String" %>

   <c:if test="${empty pattern}">
       <c:set var="pattern" value="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
   </c:if>

   <fmt:parseDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="parsedDate" type="date"/>
   <fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" type="date" pattern="${pattern}"/>
   ```
4. Go to the JSP file in which you want display the `java.time.LocalDate`.

   4.1. Add taglib directive `<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>` at the top of the file.

   4.2. Use the `localDate` tag as follows:

   - `<tags:localDate date="${yourDateToPrint}"/>`
   - `<tags:localDate date="${yourDateToPrint}" pattern="${yourPatternFormat}"/>`

Comment: Great. Thank you for it.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by `fmt:parseDate`.Try following:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${dateForParsing}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="parsedDate" type="date" />

<fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" var="newParsedDate" type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
```

I hope this help you.[More information](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/parseDate.html)

Comment: This is fine, but do you know any more direct method?

Comment: No.But you can create you own custom function for this.

Comment: Your hints inspired me to create below solution, so I marked it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the annotation @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateAdapter.class) on your javabean:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateAdapter.class)
public LocalDate getLoanDate() {
    return loanDate;
}
```